# Immutable: nested property treated like undefined

Tags: reactjs, immutability, flowtype

I know that one of Flow's caveats is 'undefined' error even when we are checking that our variable is not undefined.

As I won't be able to change this, I want to skip this error. I have read about $FlowFixMe, but I would like to have another kind of skip condition. Not actually, "FixMe"

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

I copy the error I am trying to skip

```
if (Im.Iterable.isIterable(nextProps.cliente)) {
  if (nextProps.cliente.get('clte_Codigo') !== null) {
```

Flow Error is: "get is missing for undefined"/

Comment: How are your props specified for this components? Could you supply your props definition please.

Comment: My props are of the type:  type ClienteProps = {
  cliente?: Im.Collection<string, Object>,
  candidato?: Im.Collection<string, Object>
}

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error, is because `nextProps.cliente` is potentially unset (`undefined`/`null`). An additional check in your condition is the correct solution:

`js
if (Im.Iterable.isIterable(nextProps.cliente)) {
  if (nextProps.cliente && nextProps.cliente.get('clte_Codigo') !== null) {`

---

Sidenote: Next time you post, please add more code because context is king